# Local storage returns undefined to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="radio" id="<%=(index+1)%>" class="changeprice" data-price="<%= caricature_type.price %>" value = "<%=(index+1)%>" name="studio_order[style_id]" />
```

On the click of this .changeprice, I am writing this.id to the local storage like this

```
var currentid = this.id;
console.log("current id is "+currentid);
localStorage.setItem("previous_style",parseInt(currentid));
```

`And localStorage.getItem('previous_style') also returns 2,3`. Based on the element id. So now, previous_style_id is becoming undefined in the following snippet.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('previous_style') !== null){
        var previous_style_id = localStorage.getItem('previous_style');
        $('.changeprice #'+ previous_style_id ).trigger('click');
    }else{
        $('.changeprice').first().trigger('click');
    }
```

I want to target both class and id in the first html element. That is why the following line
`$('.changeprice #'+ previous_style_id ).trigger('click');`

EDIT:

The reason I have choosen to target with the help of both class and id is.

I have other elements like this

```
<div class="choose-bottles" id="1">bottle1 </div>
```

So simply targeting the id would mean, I would target the unintended elements.

Comment: [The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `,` to specify multiple selectors.

```
$('.changeprice ,#'+ previous_style_id ).trigger('click');
```

If `input element` is to be selected using class as well as ID selector, then you should not have `space` in between.

```
 $('.changeprice#'+ previous_style_id ).trigger('click');
```

Comment: the input has both, id and `changeprice` class

Comment: it make sense, but about solving the issue I don't know, without seeing the entire HTML it's hard to know what make "previous_style_id is becoming undefined in the following snippet" when OP use duplicate ids